# if then else statement will not loop properly

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

I figured how to get an `if then else` statement to work but it now seems to have broken. =( I cannot work out what is going wrong!

There are up to 10 directories in `./` called `barcode01 - 09` and one called unclassified. This script is supposed to go into each one, prep the directory for `~/Taxonomy.R` (Which requires all the fastq files to be gzipped and put into a sub-directory titled "data". It then runs the `~/Taxonomy.R` script to make a metadata file for each.

**Edit** the `tmp.txt` file is created using `ls > tmp.txt` then `echo "0" >> tmp.txt` to make a sacrificial list of directories for the script to chew through then stop when it gets to 0.

```
#!/bin/bash

source deactivate
source activate R-Env

value=(sed -n 1p tmp.txt)

if [ "$value" = "0" ]
then 
    rm tmp.txt
else
    cd "$(sed -n 1p tmp.txt)"
    gzip *fastq
    #
    for i in *.gz
    do
        mv "$i" "${i%.*}_R1.fastq.gz"; 
    done

    #this adds the direction identifier "R1" to all the fastq.gzips
    mkdir Data
    mv *gz Data
    ~/Taxonomy3.R
    cd Data
    mv * ..
    cd ..
    rm -r Data
    cd ..
    sed '1d' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
    mv tmp2.txt tmp.txt
fi
```

Currently, it is only making the metadata file in the first barcode directory.

Comment: As a general piece of advice, it would improve the readability of your code if you indented it using a fixed amount of white space for each block.

Comment: It would help if you showed a sample tmp.txt, sample directory structure with file in them, and a sample expected result.  We can try and deduce it, but the easiest you make it for us, the better answers (and faster) you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent your code, things will get a lot clearer.
On the other hand, modifying your tmp.txt file this way id slow and dangerous. Better traverse its contents only reading it.

```
#!/bin/bash
source deactivate
source activate R-Env

for value in $(<tmp.txt)
do
    cd "$value"
    gzip *fastq

    for i in *.gz
    do
        # This adds the direction identifier "R1" to all the fastq.gzips
        mv "$i" "${i%.*}_R1.fastq.gz"
    done

    mkdir Data
    mv *gz Data
    ~/Taxonomy3.R
    mv Data/* .
    rmdir Data

    cd -
done
rm tmp.txt
```

With this reworked script you only need to create the `tmp.txt` file WITHOUT adding any marker at the end (in fact, you never needed it, you could have checked for empty file).

For each folder in the script, the operations you wanted are executed. I simplified some folder changing, minimizing it to the required ones for the R script to properly run. To go back, I used `cd -`, which goes to the previous folder, that way you can have more than one leven in your `tmp.txt` file.

Hope everything else is clear.